# Use Trigger to copy data from a table to another (VTiger)

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, updates, vtiger

I'm sorry for such a newbie question, but I have two tables:

vtiger_assets

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| assetid   | account | Stat | Key | Default | assetname      |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| 224       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| 225       | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| 226       | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| 227       | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| 228       | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| 229       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| 230       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And vtiger_assetscf

```
+--------------+---------+
| assetid      | cf_658  |
+--------------+---------+
| 224          | Value 1 |
| 225          | Value 2 |
| 226          | Value 3 |
| 227          | Value 2 |
| 228          | Value 3 |
| 229          | Value 1 |
| 230          | Value 3 |
+--------------+---------+
```

After one day of trying and errors using Trigger, INSERT and UPDATE I give up and decided to ask the experts...

A new row is added in both tables at the same time (with a new assetid automatically added)

I need to automatically import and update (populate) the values from cf_658 column at vtiger_assetcf table to the assetname column at vtiger_assets table.

I have tried:

```
create trigger 'ativos' after insert on vtiger_assetscf
for each row
begin
insert into vtiger_assets (assetid, assetname) values (new.assetid, new.cf_658);
end#
```

I have tried a combination of INSERT and UPDATE. No luck...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have used single quotes around the name.  That should cause a syntax error.  Try this:

```
delimiter #

create trigger ativos after insert on vtiger_assetscf
for each row
begin
insert into vtiger_assets(assetid, assetname)
    values (new.assetid, new.cf_658);
end; #
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had used the quotes just for example. I have used without the quotes and get "MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'assetid' in 'NEW'" But this is not the way to go... I think I'm making another mistake. A deeper one.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have already solved your problem. If not, I may have some questions to clarify:

1.- What do you mean with

> A new row is added in both tables at the same time[...]

Is it that you use one call to the DB in which you insert both rows? Because I guess you are doing two queries on one call. One that inserts into **vtiger_assets** and then one that inserts into **vtiger_assetscf**

If it is the case, maybe you are triggering the `ativos`trigger before you have the row from wich to copy the data.

2.- With

> with a new assetid automatically added

I supose you have your `auto_increment`property enabled for the **assetid** column, but this makes me wonder, why do you have separate tables if one just copy data recently sent?

Maybe you could send one query only to **vtiger_assets** and have a trigger in that table (not into **vtiger_assetscf**) that creates a new row into **vtiger_assetscf** (but now I think maybe your tables are not completely shown here....)

3.- Finally: Is your **`assetid`** a key column? (if you're using auto_increment, I bet it is). If it's the case, I think the error you get is that you try to insert a row in a table with a duplicate value (the `assetid`).

Maybe try this instead:

```
create trigger `ativos` after insert on `vtiger_assetscf`
for each row
begin
update `vtiger_assets` SET `assetname` = new.`cf_658` WHERE `assetid` = NEW.`assetid`;
end#
```

I know It's been a while, but still...